# Higher-order triangle numbers

Tags: number-theory

It's well known that the nth triangle number is given by $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^ni$.

But what about having nested sums? Consider the following examples and the final recursive definition:

$$T_n^0=1$$

$$T_n^1=\sum_{i=1}^nT_i^0=\sum_{i=1}^n1=n$$

$$T_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^nT_i^1=\sum_{i=1}^n{\sum_{j=1}^i1}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$T_n^3=\sum_{i=1}^nT_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n{\sum_{j=1}^i{\sum_{k=1}^j1=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}}}$$

$$T_n^p=\sum_{i=1}^nT_i^{p-1}=\ ?$$

What could be a closed form for the general $T_n^p$?

Comment: The pattern will repeat, I think.  That is $T_n^p={n+p-1\choose p}$  One should be able to prove this using telescoping series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as the binomial coefficients.

To see why, think about Pascal's triangle:

[image]

It's well known that the numbers in the third diagonal are triangular numbers. Because of the hockey stick formula, the fourth diagonal are just partial sums of the third. The fifth are partial sums of the fourth. etc. The closed form will be, as sauslpatz said, $T_n^p=\binom{n+p-1}{p}$, as it is also well known that the numbers in Pascal's triangle are the binomial coefficients.

Comment: This was easier than I thought, thanks a lot!